# Erroneous "No route matches" error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

This is my first time integrating stripe.  I have set pages#purchase as my homepage.  I am using a payments_controller to handle the stripe payment.
Error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/payments/create"):
```

Routes

```
resources :payments, only: [:create]
```

Rake Routes

```
payments POST   /payments(.:format) payments#create
```

Pages/Purchase

```
<%= form_tag "/payments/create" do %>
  <%= render partial: "shared/stripe_checkout_button" %>
<% end %>
```

Shared/_stripe_checkout_button

```
<script
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
  data-image="/square-image.png"
  data-name="Demo Site"
  data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
  data-amount="2000">
</script>
```

Payments Controller

```
def create #You want might to make actions more specific.
    token = params[:stripeToken] #The token when the form is posted includes the stripe token in the url.
    # Create the charge in stripes servers.  This is what commits the transaction.
    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => 200,
        :currency => "usd",
        :source => token,
        :description => params[:stripeEmail]
        )
      rescue Stripe::CardError => e 
        #The card was decline because of number/ccv error, expired error, bank decline, or zip error

        body = e.json_body
        err = body[:error]
        flash[:error] = "There was an error in processing your card: #{err[:message]}"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [`form_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) *url* is wrong. It must be :

```
<%= form_tag "/payments" do %>
  <%= render partial: "shared/stripe_checkout_button" %>
<% end %>
```

The `:method` for the form defaults to **POST**.